# itertools write to multiple files and on separate lines

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have this script that make multiple combinations of words:

```
import itertools
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

list = ['Mark', 'Jones', 'Albert', 'Mary', 'Bob']

combs = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list, 5)

for item in combs:    
    print(item)
    with open('output{0}.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.writelines(item)
```

The problem is that the output file has no spaces between words and all words are on the same line, I tried multiple solutions but non worked. Also I tried to write every 10 iterations in a separate file but couldn't find a solution for that as well

I would really appreciate any suggestions

Thanks

this is how the output file looks like

```
MarkMarkMarkMarkMarkMarkMarkMarkMarkJones
```

Here is what it is supposed to look like

```
Mark Mark Mark Mark Mark
Mark Mark Mark Mark Jones
```

Comment: Avoid using `list` as variable name, as it will override the built-in list constructor in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use the `join` method to concatenate the words in each combination with a space in between.
- add a newline character `\n` at the end of each line to ensure that each combination is written on a separate line in the output file.

```py
import itertools

my_list = ['Mark', 'Jones', 'Albert', 'Mary', 'Bob']

combs = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(my_list, 5)

with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    for item in combs:
        line = ' '.join(item) + '\n'
        print(line)
        f.write(line)
```

you can use a `counter` variable to keep track of the number of iterations and create a new file every 10 iterations.

```
import itertools

my_list = ['Mark', 'Jones', 'Albert', 'Mary', 'Bob']

combs = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(my_list, 5)

counter = 0
file_counter = 1

for item in combs:
    counter += 1
    line = ' '.join(item) + '\n'
    print(line)
    
    with open(f'output{file_counter}.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(line)
    
    if counter == 10:
        counter = 0
        file_counter += 1
```

- counter variable that keeps track of the number of iterations & After writing each combination to the current file, the counter is incremented.
- When the counter reaches 10, a new file is created by incrementing the `file_counter` variable. This process repeats until all combinations are processed.

Comment: That works perfectly but how to output every 10 iterations into a separate txt file

Comment: @Amr use counter, will edit in bit.

Comment: @Amr eddited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a newline between each combination `item`, you can append one like so

```
import itertools
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

list = ['Mark', 'Jones', 'Albert', 'Mary', 'Bob']

combs = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list, 5)

with open('output{0}.txt', 'a') as f:  # better to open the file only once
    for item in combs:  # *then* iterate over the combinations
        f.write(f'{" ".join(item)}\n')  # insert the 'item' followed by a newline
```

`join()` is used to convert the `item` tuple into a space-delimited string,
otherwise the `item` tuple is written to the file like so: `('Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'Mark')` instead of `Mark Mark Mark Mark Mark`

Answer (score -1):

Use
`print(item, file=f)`
instead of
`f.writelines(item)`.
The function `print` adds a newline character to the end of any printing, by default.

Alternatively, you can keep using `writelines`, but you'd have to concatenate a newline on the end.

Answer (score -1):

first you should open the file before the for cycle

second add a newline to the item

```py
with open('output{0}.txt', 'a') as f:
    for item in combs:    
        print(item)
        f.writelines(str(item) + '\n')
```